# Why does this call to aspnet_compiler not produce new .NET assemblies?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-web-roles, aspnet-compiler

I'm trying to make Visual Studio precompile my ASP.NET application that will be deployed on Azure. I've added the following to my .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Starting AspNetCompiler for $(ProjectDir)" Importance="high" />
    <AspNetCompiler
        VirtualPath="/"
        PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)"
    />
</Target>
```

Now when I ask Visual Studio to prepare a service package the following appears in the build output:

```
Starting AspNetCompiler for [PathToMyProject]
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p [PathToMyProject]
```

If I plant an error in any of the view files that error is identified and breaks the build so clearly the precompilation is perfomed.

Yet I don't see any new .NET assemblies anywhere in the results.

How do I make ASP.NET compiler create the .NET assemblies for the views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify an output directory you should find the output in this folder:

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\some-random-id** (try sorting on the date modified to find the latest directory).

When calling the **aspnet_compiler.exe** you can also append an output folder to the command:

```
aspnet_compiler -v "/" -p "C:\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1" C:\CompileOutput
```

Here you see the output in my C:\CompiledOutput folder

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to obtain that random folder path after the precompilation and copy the stuff from there? I'm not very optimistic about hardcoding the path.

Comment: I don't know how to access the random folder, but since you're using MSBuild you can simply modify the task like this: `<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="/" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" TargetPath="$(ProjectDir)..\PreCompiledOutput" />`. This will output everything to a PreCompiledOutput folder in your Solution Directory and you can copy the files from that folder and clean it up afterwards.