# What does Aspnet_compiler.exe do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aspnet-compiler, pre-compilation

I'm trying to pre-compile views for our MVC5.1 application to improve first load performance (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018962/precompile-during-publish-for-azure-web-services) for more context).

I'm playing with `aspnet_compiler.exe`:

```
aspnet_compiler -p d:/path/to/myapp/ -v myapp
```

I can definately see the compilation going on - warnings about `Obsolete` methods usage. But where does it put the results?

Before the experiment I've cleaned `Temporary Asp.Net Files`, just to see the result. And after the compilation finish, nothing happened. Both `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` and `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` were still empty.

I also tried executing with exact path for virtual path

```
aspnet_compiler -p d:/path/to/myapp/ -v d:/tmp/myapp
```

and that folder was left empty. But second run of the compiler was much quicker, because I did not clean the build. This makes me think the results are available somewhere.

So my questions are: where does it store the results of compilation? **and how can I make IIS use these results instead of Just-In-Time compilation?**

**Update:** I have found how to capture the output of compilation. Just specify a path as a last (or first) parameter:

```
aspnet_compiler -p d:/path/to/myapp/ -v / d:/tmp/myapp
```

This leave the question, how can I make IIS to pick it up?

Comment: Perhaps by looking at the folder indicated here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743021/why-does-this-call-to-aspnet-compiler-not-produce-new-net-assemblies?rq=1

Comment: you mean `Temporaty ASP.Net Files` folder? that was empty for me. I've found how I can specify the target - see update. Question is how I can make IIS to use results of that compilation in `Temporaty ASP.Net Files`

Comment: I didn't have time to dig into but these two docs should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479044.aspx   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx